# YouTube Ads Display in Flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube

I'm in the process of developing a Flutter app that utilizes the [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) package to incorporate YouTube video playback functionality seamlessly. While the package works well for playing videos, I've noticed that advertisements aren't appearing during video playback. This concern has already been discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/issues/117).

Quote from [Google's policy](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en):

> Ads appear on brand safe sites: YouTube works diligently so that our
> advertisers' brands appear on sites that reflect our respective core
> values. Our systems closely evaluate websites and their content
> against various factors when finding out whether to turn on In-stream
> ads on YouTube embeds

I want to ensure my app complies with Google's ad policies and prevent potential issues down the line. Has anyone tackled this specific issue while using the youtube_player_flutter package in a released app? Or does Google activate ads for apps, after reviewing them. I'd greatly appreciate any insights or solutions that can shed light on this matter.

Considering that Flutter is a Google product, I'm also curious if anyone has experience reaching out to Google for clarification. Are there any recommended starting points or channels for establishing communication with Google's team regarding ad display in apps developed with Flutter? Your advice and experiences will be invaluable in helping me navigate this situation effectively.